# Prove $\text{lim} \ b^n=0$ for $0 < \vert b \vert< 1$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

My work starts with a supposition of $N$, so that for $n > N$ we have $\vert b \vert ^n < \epsilon$.

Since $0 < \vert b \vert < 1$, we see the logarithm with base $\vert b \vert$ is a decrescent function meaning it will invert the inequality once taken.
$$\vert b \vert ^n < \epsilon $$
$$n > \text{log}_{\vert b \vert}\epsilon $$

Done the scrapwork, lets start the formal proof.
Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $N = \text{log}_{\vert b \vert}\epsilon$. If $n > N$ and $0 < \vert b \vert< 1$, then
$$\vert b \vert ^n < \vert b \vert ^{\text{log}_{\vert b \vert}\epsilon} = \epsilon$$
Hence by definition, $\text{lim} \ b^n=0$

Have I done everything correctly? I am using in an implicit manner that $\vert b^n \vert = \vert b \vert ^n$, is everything fine with this? (Something is really pinching me up!)

Comment: $\vert b^n \vert = \vert b \vert ^n$ is fine for natural numbers $n$ and easily proved by induction.  It is also true for real $n$ but not complex $n$

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: What bothers me is: How do you know that $N$ exists?

Comment: Good question. I guessed that $\text{log}_{\vert b \vert}$ is a continuous function and since $\epsilon > 0$, it would be an acceptable argument for the function. Do you think it needs to be further proved? (In that case, I can see why mathematicians prefer elementary resources to demonstrate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make janmarqz's result
more explicit.

Since
$|b^n| = |b|^n$,
we can assume that
$0 < b < 1$.

Then
$b = \dfrac1{1+a}$
with $a > 0$,
so that,
from Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+a)^n \ge 1+an
$.

Therefore,
since
$a = \dfrac1{b}-1$,

$\begin{array}\\
b^n
&=\dfrac1{(1+a)^n}\\
&\le \dfrac1{1+na}\\
&\lt \dfrac1{na}\\
&=\dfrac1{n(\frac1{b}-1)}\\
\end{array}
$

To make
$b^n < \epsilon$,
it is enough if
$\epsilon > \dfrac1{n(\frac1{b}-1)}$
or
$n > \dfrac1{\epsilon(\frac1{b}-1)}$.

This is,
of course,
far worse than using the log,
but it is 
completely elementary.

This is also not original with me.
I first saw this in
"What is Mathematics?"
by Courant and Robbins,
which I highly recommend
and is available in paperback
for less than $20.

Comment: I liked your explicit answer. Is it wrong to use log as I did? I am doubtful if it is possible to use such function in real analysis.

Comment: No. Using log is fine. It actually produces a much better result. I just like this because it is completely elementary.

Comment: I accepted your answer because I feel it is very didactic (I am new to this). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If $0<|b|<1$ then $|b|=\frac{1}{1+A}$ for some $A>0$.
But $(1+A)^n\ge 1+nA$ for each $n\in \Bbb N$, so you have $$|b|^n=\frac{1}{(1+A)^n}\le\frac{1}{1+nA}$$
Now taking $n$ large enough you are going to reach $\frac{1}{1+nA}<\varepsilon$, for each $\varepsilon>0$. Hence $|b|^n$ too.

Comment: That is exactly the way I would have shown this.  (+1)

Answer (score 3):

My answer can be over killing, but it has different view point.

If $0<|b|<1$, note that

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|b|^n = \frac{1}{1-|b|} <\infty$.

Thus, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|b|^n=0$ so

$|\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} b^n|\leq |\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|b|^n| =0$ $\implies \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}b^n=0$.

Comment: I have always liked this approach to certain limits. Unfortunately, the formula for the sum of a geometric series of ratio $r$ of absolute value less than 1 requires showing that $|r|^n$ has limit 0 as $n$ approaches infinity.